# Do built-in kernel drivers need kfree?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, driver

For a device driver that is compiled into the Linux kernel, should kmalloc'ed memory be freed with corresponding kfree() calls?

I am talking about memory that's allocated on initialization once and not something that is continuously allocated during the driver's lifespan. I assume that freeing the allocated memory is not necessary because the built-in driver lifespan is the lifespan of the kernel. Yes, the allocated memory is necessary for driver operation and cannot be freed after driver init; i.e. no __init macro possible.

I have not seen the above stated explicitly, and want to be sure.

Comment: How will the driver know at coding time if it will be compiled as built in or as module?

Comment: @Miline, there are few modules that can't be compiled as a module. They are usually marked by bool selector in Kconfig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. But very few modules (which are drivers) can't be compiled as such. Moreover it's a good programming style.

By the way, you may consider to use device managed resources, like memory allocated via `devm_kzalloc`. It will take care of the allocated resources on probe stage and allows you to clean up an error path there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about `devm_kzalloc `. In this case the driver is for low-level initialization of an embedded device. The device cannot function with this driver unloaded.

Comment: Put a bool selector to its `Kconfig` option and feel free to use regular `kzalloc()`, though still be careful.